# Eclipse is running on same constraints, after changing the data

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse Kepler with jdk 1.6, problem is with particular system, on other system everything is fine.
 I have created a java project in eclipse, in main class i have some variables(constraints) on which the whole project works, for purpose of testing, when i am changing the variables data and executing eclipse giving result on some previously fixed variables, don't know why this silly behavior.
If somebody knows the issue please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your project. If your project need to re-build for every change you made, than maybe you have turned off live-build in eclipse.

If your project does not need any building, may be it is because of environment in which you are working. sometimes it happens. just restart eclipse. may be it helps. but if problem still persist, let me know more details about your project and eclipse.

Thanks,

Comment: Ye live build is on, refresh, cleanup and restarting Eclipse is also of no use.

Comment: If eclipse is working fine on other project, than problem with your project. in that case let me know your project structure if I can help. If eclipse showing same problem on other projects also, than problem with eclipse. re-install it and reset jre and jdk.

Comment: Yes it is fine on other projects,  and the same project working on other machine Eclipse with same configuration.

Comment: My projects uses core Java.

Comment: In that case, update JDK and JRE as well. because sometime, due to inter -compatibility of JDK and JRE this happens. here is the link to latest JDK and JRE: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: before that, once try to remove project from eclipse. than re import it. so that .classpath also be refreshed and updated.

Comment: this is the solution which i already know, but this is very awkward to re import the project every time.

Comment: Not every time. this time only. after that just don't change in library which you imported for your project. because that will change your .classpath file.

Comment: I have been used the above method quite a few time, but it can hang anytime which i am facing... Thanks for kind response.